# How to save line numbers in scripts?

Tags: powershell-core

Trying to tell a script to save line number as variable.

Works fine in Windows Powershell, and if I put it into PS Core by hand.

```
    $num = Select-String source.txt -pattern "XXXXX" | Select-Object -Expandproperty LineNumber
```

But running a script with PS Core that calls another script, that bit isn't working for me. The "Get-Variable" returns blank.

Edit: In PowerShell-6.1.0-preview.2

Also tried it all in 1 script to confirm it's not playing nice with line numbers.

```
$path = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
cd $path
$mc = "1.12.2"
$mv = $mc
$mod = "armor-chroma"
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$mod = "https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/$mod/files"
$client.DownloadFile("$mod/files","$path\source.txt")
$num = Select-String source.txt -pattern "  $mv</option>" | Select-Object -Expandproperty LineNumber
Get-Variable num
pause
```

Again, works with copy&paste (setting $path by hand,) but "Get-Variable num" returns blank when I run the .ps1 with PowerShell Core.

Comment: Works for me in 6.0.2.

Comment: Not working for me in "PowerShell-6.1.0-preview.2-win-x64"